# Error - cannot call member function without object in C++

Tags: c++, class

I get the compile error

`cannot call member function ‘bool GMLwriter::write(const char*, MyList<User*>&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)’ without object`

when I try to compile

```
 class GMLwriter{
    public:
    bool write(const char *fn, MyList<User*>& my_vec, vector<string>edges);
};
```

the function is defined later and called in `main` with

`GMLwriter::write(argv[3], Users, edges);`

Users is declared before with `MyList<User*> Users;` (MyList is a List ADT and I have a User class) and edges is declared with `vector<string>edges`

to what `object` is this error referring?

Comment: How do you **call** this function? You need to show that part of the code to get an correct answer instead of guesses.

Comment: @AlokSave `GMLwriter::write(argv[3], Users, edges);`

Comment: Well then that is **not a definition**, In C++ to be able to call a non-static member function you need a class object. something like: `GMLwriter obj; obj.write(...);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`GMLwriter::write` is not static function of GMLwriter, you need to call it through object. For example:

```
GMLwriter gml_writer;   
gml_writer.write(argv[3], Users, edges);
```

If `GMLwriter::write` doesn't depend on any GMLwriter state(access any member of `GMLwriter`), you can make it a static member function. Then you could call it directly without object:

```
class GMLwriter
{
public:
   static bool write(const char *fn, MyList<User*>& my_vec, vector<string>edges);
   ^^^^
};
```

then you could call:

```
GMLwriter::write(argv[3], Users, edges);
```

Answer (score 1):

`GMLwriter` is not an object, it's a class type.

Calling member functions requires an object instance, ie:

```
GMLwriter foo;   
foo.write(argv[3], Users, edges);
```

Although there's a good chance you intended the function to be free or static:

```
class GMLwriter{
    public:
    // static member functions don't use an object of the class,
    // they are just free functions inside the class scope
    static bool write(const char *fn, MyList<User*>& my_vec, vector<string>edges);
};

// ...
GMLwriter::write(argv[3], Users, edges);
```

or

```
bool write(const char *fn, MyList<User*>& my_vec, vector<string>edges);
// ...
write(argv[3], Users, edges);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to call / create a static method, to be

In this case, you might want to precede your declaration with a 'static' modifier.

http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/classes/Lesson12b.htm